# Ocaml - unexpected output

Tags: output, ocaml

I have following code presented below:

```
let str = "AA";;
let i =ref 0;;
let tam_str = String.length str -1;;
let aux_char = 'A';;
let b_aux1 = ref false;;
exception Out_of_loop;;

try
  while !i <= tam_str do
    let c_r = str.[!i] in
    if c_r = aux_char then(
      b_aux1 := true;
      i := !i +1;
    )
    else(
      b_aux1 := false;
      raise Out_of_loop
    )
  done;
with Out_of_loop ->();
if !b_aux1 then
  print_endline "1"
else
  print_endline "0";
;;
```

I expected the program to write the string "1" but it is returning "unit". But I don't understand why ... Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful of the precedence of the various constructs. You have written

```ml
try ...
with Out_of_loop ->
  begin
    ();
    if !b_aux1 then ...
  end
```

while I suppose you wanted to write

```ml
begin
  try ...
  with Out_of_loop -> ()
end;
if !b_aux1 then ...
```